# reportlab different next page

Tags: python, reportlab

I am trying to produce a PDF document with different odd/even page layouts (to allow asymmetric borders for binding) using Python 2.7 and ReportLab. To further complicate matters I am trying to produce two-columns per page.

```
def WritePDF(files):

    story = []
    doc = BaseDocTemplate("Polar.pdf", pagesize=A4, title = "Polar Document 5th Edition")

    oddf1  = Frame(doc.leftMargin, doc.bottomMargin, doc.width/2-6, doc.height, id='oddcol1') 
    oddf2  = Frame(doc.leftMargin+doc.width/2+6, doc.bottomMargin, doc.width/2-6, doc.height, id='oddcol2')
    evenf1 = Frame(doc.leftMargin, doc.bottomMargin, doc.width/2-6, doc.height, id='evencol1') 
    evenf2 = Frame(doc.leftMargin+doc.width/2+6, doc.bottomMargin, doc.width/2-6, doc.height, id='evencol2')
    doc.addPageTemplates([PageTemplate(id='EvenTwoC',frames=[evenf1,evenf2],onPage=evenFooter),
                          PageTemplate(id='OddTwoC', frames=[oddf1, oddf2], onPage=oddFooter)])


    ...

    story.append(Paragraph(whatever, style))
```

What I can't figure out is how to make ReportLab alternate between right and left (or odd and even) pages. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you need [this](http://www.reportlab.com/apis/reportlab/2.4/platypus.html#reportlab.platypus.doctemplate.NextPageTemplate) and there you will calculate if the page is odd(right) or even(left) (or the opposite)... I'll need to check this though, and I'll post an answer.

Comment: I can (and have) used the NextPageTemplate function to maually set what the next page is - for example after I've appended the Paragraph()s for (say) a title page I can then set the next page to a different style. My problem is that I am automatically typesetting thousands of Paragraphs() and I conjecture that what I need to do is set something up in the BaseDocTemplate (or possibly the PageTemplate) which will alternate between page templates so the left template sets the right template for the next page and vice versa.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the solution I guess ! :)

I had to dig into the source code. I found the solution in the file `reportlab/platypus/doctemplate.py` on line 636. It's not the first time I had to do this, as the documentation is pretty limited...

Now, what I found:

```
def handle_nextPageTemplate(self,pt):
        '''On endPage change to the page template with name or index pt'''
        if type(pt) is StringType:
            # ... in short, set self._nextPageTemplate
        elif type(pt) is IntType:
            # ... in short, set self._nextPageTemplate
        elif type(pt) in (ListType, TupleType):
            #used for alternating left/right pages
            #collect the refs to the template objects, complain if any are bad
            c = PTCycle()
            for ptn in pt:
                found = 0
                if ptn=='*':    #special case name used to short circuit the iteration
                    c._restart = len(c)
                    continue
                for t in self.pageTemplates:
                    if t.id == ptn:
                        c.append(t)
                        found = 1
                if not found:
                    raise ValueError("Cannot find page template called %s" % ptn)
            if not c:
                raise ValueError("No valid page templates in cycle")
            elif c._restart>len(c):
                raise ValueError("Invalid cycle restart position")

            #ensure we start on the first one
            self._nextPageTemplateCycle = c.cyclicIterator()
        else:
            raise TypeError("argument pt should be string or integer or list")
```

And I checked where this `self._nextPageTemplateCycle` is used, so this is what I think should work (not tested though):

```
story = []
# ...
# doc.addPageTemplates([...])

story.append(NextPageTemplate(['pageLeft', 'pageRight'])) # this will cycle through left/right/left/right/...

story.append(NextPageTemplate(['firstPage', 'secondPage', '*', 'pageLeft', 'pageRight'])) # this will cycle through first/second/left/right/left/right/...
```

Add this to story once, when you want to start alternating pages. Use another normal NextPageTemplate to stop this cycle (because in the source, there's a `del self._nextPageTemplateCycle` if you do that).

Hope it helps, and do say if it works, I can't make sure right now, but I will!

Comment: Doh! Yes, thanks you it really is that simple. The only other thing I had to do was that as I wanted the front page to be single-column I had to add that as the first entry in the list of PageTemplate()s added to the doc object. Thank you so much - I really was beating my head against a wall.

Comment: Oh! Reportlab gave that feeling so many times... And consider accepting the answer if it helped you ;) [faq#howtoask]